# como fazer controle de trafego nos app Android da Admob?

Tags: android, admob

Minha conta foi bloqueada por click inválidos, como identificar esse ip e fazer algo resolver problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infelizmente a política do admob não fornece esse tipo de informação. Passei pela mesma situação, mandei email para o suporte e etc. Sugiro que crie uma outra conta em outro endereço para liberar novamente. Na aplicação nós temos que ter muito cuidado para colocarmos o espaço do admob em um lugar que não de muitos cliques inválidos, no caso bem longe de botões e etc (lugares que o usuário poderia acidentalmente clicar) foi essa informação que eles me passaram.